# YaLinqo - Get correct result for where clause containing equals operator

Tags: php, arrays, linq, where-clause, yalinqo

I'm trying to query an array with a SQL-similar syntax and I'm getting to know YaLinqo.

I managed to have it work for where clauses with superior or inferior operators but I can't have it work with the equals operator.

What am I doing wrong?

Here an example:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use \YaLinqo\Enumerable;

$users = [
    [
        'UserId' => '1',
        'username' => 'joe',
        'password' => 'joepw',
        'mail' => 'joe@mail.com'
    ],
    [
        'UserId' => '2',
        'username' => 'nancy',
        'password' => 'nancypw',
        'mail' => 'nancy@mail.com'
    ],
    [
        'UserId' => '3',
        'username' => 'alice',
        'password' => 'alicepw',
        'mail' => 'alice@mail.com'
    ]
];

$working = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
    ->where('$users ==> $users["UserId"] > 2')
    ->toArray();

$notWorking = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
    ->where('$users ==> $users["UserId"] = 2')
    ->toArray();

$workingAndUgly = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
    ->where('$users ==> $users["UserId"] > 1')
    ->where('$users ==> $users["UserId"] < 3')
    ->toArray();

$notWorkingEither = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
    ->where('$users ==> $users["username"] = "nancy"')
    ->toArray();

var_dump($working, $notWorking, $workingAndUgly, $notWorkingEither);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that using `==` instead of `=` works:

```
// previously $notWorking
$nowWorking = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
    ->where('$users ==> $users["UserId"] == 2')
    ->toArray();

// previously $notWorkingEither
$nowWorkingAlso = \YaLinqo\Enumerable::from($users)
->where('$users ==> $users["username"] == "nancy"')
->toArray();
```